# How can I use SharedPreferences with a spinner

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, spinner

I want to use `SharedPreferences` to save the selected item that's chosen in the `spinner`

here is my coding

```
package com.mulder.jip.schoolroosterbeta2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustumMaandag extends Activity {

    Context Context = this;
    private Spinner les1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custum_maandag);
        {

            les1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.les1);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Test1");
            list.add("Test2");
            list.add("Test3");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);

            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                    (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            les1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            les1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
                    prefsEditor.putString("object", obj.toString());
                    prefsEditor.commit();
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @MRX I've used the wrong code while posting this question, the original code I used was 
`SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());` instead of 
`SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);`

the error is then that it can't resolve the symbol `getApplicationContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this inside `onItemSelected(...){ *here }`

```
String selectedText = les1.getSelectedItem().toString();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs_name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("your_key", selectedText);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
String selecteditem = les1 .getSelectedItem().toString();
```

and save in shared pref like this

```
 prefsEditor.putString("object", selecteditem );
```

Comment: after this line les1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);